# Existence proof of a closest point

Tags: real-analysis

In $(X,d) $ be a metric space. Define $d_A: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ by $d_A(x)= \inf \{ d(x,a): a\in A \}$. Prove that in $\mathbb{R}^ n, A \subset X $ is closed implies that $(\forall x \in X)(\exists $ an element $a \in A)$ such that $d_A(x) = d(a,x).$

I want this proof to be rigorous. First I tried this $a$ does not exist but I could not find a contradiction because I could not comment on such thing $\inf \phi$. I do not even know if the proof is necessary or it directly follows by definition.? Can you give me a starting point and route such that I can use closedness to prove this fact.?

Comment: What metric are you using on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Question did not specifically indicate it. So I assumed it to be usual euclidian metric

Comment: Then you can use a compactness argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $l=d_A(x)$. Then for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a point $a_n\in A$ such that $l\le d(x,a_n)\le l+\frac{1}{n}$. Since $a_n\in B_{l+1}(x)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Here $B_{l+1}(x)$ is the clsoed ball of radius $l+1$ centred at $x$. Then there is a convergent subsequence of $\{a_{n_k}\}$. Let $a=\lim_{k\to \infty} a_{n_k}$. Then we have $d_A(x)=d(a,x)$.

Comment: I could not spot where you used the closedness of A?

Comment: Since each $a_n\in A$, it follows that $a$ is in the closure of $A$, which is $A$ itself.

Comment: How did you conclude that there is a convergent sequence?

Comment: Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem

Comment: That depends on the metric.

Comment: Right. X has to be a complete metric space.

Comment: The space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ I described below is complete, so that is not sufficient to conclude the existence of a minimiser.

Comment: @copper.hat You are absolutely right. I need something stronger so that Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem holds.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general.

Define the (railroad express)  metric on $\mathbb{R}$ by  $d(x,y) =\begin{cases} 0 , & x=y \\
|x|+|y|, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

The set $A=(1,\infty)$ is closed in this metric, but,
with $x=1$, we have 
$d(x,a) >1$ for all $a \in A$, while $\inf_{a \in A} d(x,a) = 1$.

Comment: Isn't $ \inf _{a\in A} d(x,a) = 2$  by the definiton of metric?

Comment: You are correct, I will fix when I get to my laptop.